# How to check Apache configuration on shared server?

Tags: laravel, apache, hosting

I am trying to upload a Laravel app to a shared server, GoDaddy to be precise. I'm getting an error that is probably related to the next configuration.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I need to know how I can check if my shared server Apache has the same configuration.

Comment: What error you are getting? On shared servers you will get mostly CPanel and WHM from which you can set these configurations

Comment: Its a The requested URL was not found on this server, thats the error im getting, I think is related to httpd.conf access granted all config, I know this could be solved by using some code in the .htaccesss but seems their https.conf has not enable override or maybe I am placing the htaccess file in the wrong path

Comment: Im gonna switch my host solutions to digital ocean or some vps service that allow me to configure my services

Comment: Hey Alex, before changing the hosting provider, you can check cpanel of your current godaddy server and check what is the document root of your domain. Firstly do like echo 'working'; exit at the start of your public/index.php and check if its working. I think your document root pointing is incorrect. If it reaches to index.php then you can proceed checking the mod rewrites